# how to properly call passed function in child component

Tags: reactjs

i've got this 2 components and i'm wondering how to call passed function. Because if i pass it -> i've got a reference to it in a child so the problem appears when i want to pass a paremeter to it - because its immediately calling ( this is clear ).

```
class Parent extends Component {
  ....
  fn = (arg) => {console.log(arg)}
  render(){
    return (
      <Child myPassedFn={this.fn}>delete</button>
    )
  }
}

class Child extends Component {
 render(){
    return (
      <button onClick={this.props.myPassedFn('lul')}>delete</button>
    )
  }
}
```

in this way as soon as component `Child` renders, `myPassedFn` will execute

So is this a right approach to make it happen ? Because i want to make thinks, you know, in a most clear and proper way

```
class Child extends Component {

 childFn = () => {
   this.props.myPassedFn('this is how i could pass, you little..')
 }
 render(){
    return (
      <button onClick={this.childFn}>delete</button>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write it like this also:

```
onClick={() => this.props.myPassedFn('lul')}
```

`Onclick` except a `method`, and the way you are using is, method calling, it will `return` the value.

You can use the 2nd way also, above line is just the shorthand for that.

Comment: really appriciate =)

Comment: defining anonymous functions inside `render` will make it hard to optimize children rendering using `shouldComponentUpdate` as the `onClick` prop will change on every render. A better approach is to define a `_handleClick` handler on use the same handler every time the component renders